# iOS Corebluetooth in background

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

so currently I am working with a BLE device and was wondering if this was possible.

I am setting a local notification for a certain time and when I receive the notification it sends a command to the BLE device. Everything works perfectly fine in foreground mode but when I enter background mode I can't detect my notifications.

I know with the new background modes I can detect `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` and that is working properly. I am wondering if I can call `didReceiveLocalNotification` in the `didUpdateValueForCharacteristics`

Comment: you want to explicitly call didReceiveLocalNotification when app is being wakeup from the background on didUpdateValueForCharacteristics . if i understand it right?

Comment: @Imran or I wan to explicitly call `didRecieveLocalNotification` when `didUdateValueForCharacteristic` is called so I can still get notifications in the background

Comment: didUdateValueForCharacteristic will wake up your application from background and there you can handle the response . As your code get executed why not you handle it there rather then call didRecieveLocalNotification?
didRecieveLocalNotification is being call by the system also you need to understand the purpose of local notification . In doesn't make sense to call didReceiveLocalNotification explicitly  in any case